# Using multiple seeders with UIMA Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

We've tried various approaches to using multiple seeders with UIMA Ruta but can't seem to find a method that works consistently.

We tried creating 2 separate Eclipse projects: one for each seeder. In this scenario, the Parameter Setting for our custom seeder gets overwritten with the default seeder class. This seems to happen randomly - we can't pin down a cause. Any ideas?

We also tried moving both seeders within the same aggregate engine in one Eclipse project (one Ruta AE for each script with the seeder class assigned on the AE). In this scenario it seems that, regardless of the order the scripts are executed, only the first seeder is being used. The second script runs with the first script's seeder. Any ideas on this?

We would love to hear how others have successfully managed to use multiple seeders. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The multiple seeder functionality should work correctly. I just added a test [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/ruta-core/src/test/java/org/apache/uima/ruta/engine/MultipleSeedersTest.java).

Please provide more information about the version and the build environement.

Trying to answer the question: I assume you use the simple ruta projects? Maybe you set the values in the generated analysis engine description, which will be overridden by using the template RutaEngine.xml. You need the perform the changes in that description. In case you use the ruta-maven-plugin, the same applies the configuration of the template.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Peter. I was adding the seeders to the generated descriptor so that tidbit helped a lot! I added both seeders to the BasicEngine.xml file and now I'm not having issues with overwrite of the seeder list.

Comment: However, I am still having issues getting both of my seeders to show their output in the CAS. I used your test file as an example and wrote a test where I call my two seeders in code.  When I call each seeder alone, I get the results I expect in the CAS. When I call both seeders together, I only get the results from the first seeder in the list added to the CAS. Have you tested two seeders that generate different outputs? How should this behave?

Comment: I have not tested seeders with different outputs, but I do not see what could cause problems. The Ruta seeder skips adding anntoations if there are already TokenSeed annotation. Do you do something like that maybe in your seeder? The annotation of the second seeder are missing in the actual CAS vs not displayed in the CAS Editor?